# How to pass multiple Highcharts parameters in JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, highcharts

I'd like to pass some graph parameters via a JSON array to the graph. In it, it should be the title of the graph, the units, ... and clearly, the data.

As soon as I start to try to convert the JSON array from a simple "data" array to one which can hold more information, it doesn't work anymore. I guess it has something to do with the sort of brackets I am using. Being confused about which ones are the right ones.

I put it [into a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jd41gz1q/3/).

```
$(function () {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline',
        marginBottom: 50
    },
    xAxis: {
    },
    title: 
    {
        text: "Title",
        align: "center",
    },
    plotOptions:
    {
        series:
        {
            marker:
            {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{}]
};



/* This works 
data = [
          {
              "name": "France",
               "data": [[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]
          }
       ];
*/



/* This doesn't */
data = [
            {
                 "series":
                  [{
                      "name": "France",
                       "data": [[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]
                  }]
            }
       ];


/* load the stuff in the JSON like this= */
options.series  = data["series"];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Thanks a lot for any hints what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data object is array so you need to refer to first element and then to object.

```
options.series  = data[0].series;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jd41gz1q/6/

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. But how would that work then if I want to add "title" and "xAxis-title" to it in a later stage. I am still fighting with this (I guess, rather trivial) thing. In my [example fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jd41gz1q/9/) it partially works; but it looks rather wrong. What would be the correct way of doing this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: But, is this approach recommendable in general? If the order of the elements in the JSON change, the code won’t work anymore - and I’ll surely add new elements, such as copyright, xaxis, ...: `options.title  = data[0].title; options.xAxis  = data[1].xAxis; options.series  = data[2].series;` Isn’t there a more generic approach to passing those parameters via JSON and reading them out? Any hint/recommendation you have for me?

Comment: Ok. [Does work](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jd41gz1q/12/): `data = {"title": {"text": "Here goes the title"},"xAxis": {"title": {"text": "Here go the units"}},"series": [{"name": "France","data": [[2006,2189260],[2007,2239300],[2008,2237490],[2009,2167070],[2010,2204450]]}]};options.series  = data["series"];options.title  = data["title"];options.xAxis  = data["xAxis"];`